# higher order function haskell

Tags: string, haskell, higher-order-functions, fold

I'm new to Haskell, I've to do a function that counts the number of vowels in a string using the higher order function **foldr**

I've tried to create this function

```
vowels [] = 0
vowels (x:xs)= if elem x "aeiou" then 1 + vowels xs else vowels xs
```

But it doesn't work and I'm not able to do it using `foldr`, any suggestion?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: Ok now it works , but I dont know how to use foldr to have the same result

Comment: @G.Zam NB it "now works" because the Unicode quotes got replaced with the ASCII quotes.

Answer (score 8):

Well a [**`foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr) is a function where the first parameter is a function `f :: a -> b -> b`. You can here see the `a` parameter as the "*head*" of the list, the second parameter `b` as the *result* of the recursion with `foldr`, and you thus want to produce a result in terms of these two for the entire function. This logic is basically encapsulated in the second clause of your function.

Indeed:

```
vowels (x:xs) = if elem x "aeiou" then 1 + vowels xs else vowels xs
```

can be rewritten as:

```
vowels (x:xs) = if elem x "aeiou" then 1 + rec else rec
    where rec = vowels xs
```

and `rec` is thus the outcome of the recursive call, the second parameter of the "fold"-function. `x` on the other hand is the first parameter of the "fold"-function. We thus need to write this function, only in terms of `x` and `rec`, and this is simply:

```
\x rec -> if elem x "aeiou" then 1 + rec else rec
```

Furthermore we need to handle the case of an empty list, this is the first clause of your function. In that case the result is `0`, this is the second paramter of the `foldr`, so we got:

```
vowels = foldr (\x rec -> if elem x "aeiou" then 1 + rec else rec) 0
```

Or a more clean syntax:

```
vowels = foldr f 0
    where f x rec | elem x "aeiou" = 1 + rec
                  | otherwise = rec
```

We can further clean it up, by abstracting away `rec`:

```
vowels = foldr f 0
    where f x | elem x "aeiou" = (1+)
              | otherwise = id
```

Comment: Or keeping `rec` and converting the boolean value to an integer: `f x rec = rec + fromEnum (elem x "aeiou")`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to take a look at `foldr`'s signature.

`foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`

Never mind the `Foldable` part and focus on the first function it takes.
`(a -> b -> b)` `b` is the same type that you are supposed to return, so directly translating the signature into a lambda gives you `\x acc -> acc`, but you want to do more than just ignore every element.

Take a look at your function `if elem x "aeiou" then 1 + vowels xs else vowels xs`. You need to return `b`, not recurse adding one to it.

`if elem x "aeiou"` this part is fine. `then 1 + acc` <- see what I'm doing here? I'm adding one to the accumulator, not recursing manually, that is done by `foldr`, as for the `else` case: `acc`. That's it. You don't need to even touch `x`.

Putting it all together: `vowels = foldr (\x acc -> if elem x "aeiou" then 1 + acc else acc) 0`
The `0` is what the `acc` will start as.

If you want to know more about folds, I suggest you reimplement them yourself.

Comment: thanks,  but in this way it don't compile, it says: fail

Comment: @Welperooni the OP can have the "dreaded" monomorphism restriction kicking in (this could happen without the type signature); simply specify all the arguments in the definition to prevent it (i.e., `vowels xs = ...`).

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to write something like that is to let the compiler guide you.

First, look only at the *obvious* parts of the `foldr` signature. <sup><sub>This is the traditional signature, specialised to lists. Nowedays, `foldr` can actually work on any other suitable container as well, but this isn't important here.</sub></sup>

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b)  -- ^ Not obvious
      -> b              -- ^ Not obvious
      -> [a]            -- ^ A list... that'll be the input string
      -> b              -- ^ Final result, so nothing to be done here.
```

So, your implementation will be of the form

```
vowels :: String -> Int
vowels s = foldr _ _ s
```

where we yet need to find out what to put in the `_` gaps. The compiler will give you useful hints as to this:

```
$ ghc wtmpf-file6869.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( wtmpf-file6869.hs, wtmpf-file6869.o )

/tmp/wtmpf-file6869.hs:2:18: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: Char -> Int -> Int
    • In the first argument of ‘foldr’, namely ‘_’
      In the expression: foldr _ _ s
      In an equation for ‘Main.vowels’: Main.vowels s = foldr _ _ s
    • Relevant bindings include
        s :: String (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file6869.hs:2:8)
        vowels :: String -> Int (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file6869.hs:2:1)
  |
2 | vowels s = foldr _ _ s
  |                  ^
```

So, a function that merely takes a single character, and then modifies an integer. That was actually already part of your original implementation:

```
vowels (x:xs) = if elem x "aeiou" then 1 + vowels xs else vowels xs
```

The bold part is essentially a function of a single character, that yields a number-modifier. So we can put that in the `foldr` implementation, using lambda syntax:

```
vowels s = foldr (\x -> if x`elem`"aeiou" then (1+) else _) _ s
```

I had to put the `1+` in parenthesis so it works without an explicit argument, as an *operator section*.

Ok, more gaps:

```
    • Found hole: _ :: Int -> Int
    • In the expression: _
      In the expression: if x `elem` "aeiou" then (1 +) else _
      In the first argument of ‘foldr’, namely
        ‘(\ x -> if x `elem` "aeiou" then (1 +) else _)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: Char (bound at wtmpf-file6869.hs:2:20)
        s :: String (bound at wtmpf-file6869.hs:2:8)
        vowels :: String -> Int (bound at wtmpf-file6869.hs:2:1)
  |
2 | vowels s = foldr (\x -> if x`elem`"aeiou" then (1+) else _) _ s
  |                                                          ^
```

So that's the modifier that should take action when you've found a non-vowel. What do you want to modify in this case? Well, nothing actually: the count should stay as-is. That's accomplished by the `id` function.

```
vowels s = foldr (\x -> if x`elem`"aeiou" then (1+) else id) _ s
```

```
    • Found hole: _ :: Int
    • In the second argument of ‘foldr’, namely ‘_’
      In the expression:
        foldr (\ x -> if x `elem` "aeiou" then (1 +) else id) _ s
      In an equation for ‘vowels’:
          vowels s
            = foldr (\ x -> if x `elem` "aeiou" then (1 +) else id) _ s
    • Relevant bindings include
        s :: String (bound at wtmpf-file6869.hs:2:8)
        vowels :: String -> Int (bound at wtmpf-file6869.hs:2:1)
  |
2 | vowels s = foldr (\x -> if x`elem`"aeiou" then (1+) else id) _ s
  |                                                              ^
```

So that's an integer that's completely outside of the `foldr`. I.e. it can't depend on the string. In particular, it will also be used if the string is *empty*. Can only be `0`!

```
vowels s = foldr (\x -> if x`elem`"aeiou" then (1+) else id) 0 s
```

No more gaps, so the compiler will just accept this. Test it:

```
$ ghci wtmpf-file6869
GHCi, version 8.2.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/sagemuej/.ghc/ghci.conf
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/sagemuej/.ghci
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( wtmpf-file6869.hs, interpreted )
Ok, 1 module loaded.
*Main> vowels "uwkaefdohinurheoi"
9
```

Comment: you write "... an integer that's completely outside of the `foldr`. I.e. it can't depend on the string ..." this may be obvious from the general type but why should this be obvious with the specific types? what we see at that point is `vowels s = foldr (\x -> if x`elem`"aeiou" then (1+) else id) _ s`. why should that Int be free from `s`? why can't it depend on it, from what we see there? I don't see it. Can we really avoid discussing the partially-specialized type `\r z -> foldr r z "12" :: (Char -> b -> b) -> b -> b` here (and mentioning the omitted `forall b .`), before we're going to Ints?

Comment: ... in particular, I can write  `(length s)` instead of that `_`, and Haskell accepts this as a valid definition.

Comment: You're right, it's only obvious after eta-reduction. (Which isn't really a reason either, because _why can we do η-reduction_?) Do you have any better reason that could be named here?

Comment: the type `forall b . (Char -> b -> b) -> b -> b` is all I have. is it really eta-reduction? maybe it's "specification"? (or what's the word, narrowing? instantiation?)

Answer (score 1):

Your definition can be tweaked into

```
vowels []     = 0
vowels (x:xs) = g x (vowels xs)
  where
  g x rec = if elem x "aeiou" then 1 + rec else rec
```

which matches the pattern

```
foldr r z [] = z
foldr r z (x:xs) = r x (foldr r z xs)
```

if we have `foldr r z = vowels` and `r = g`, and also `z = 0`.

That "pattern" is in fact a valid definition of the `foldr` function.

Thus we indeed have

```
vowels xs = foldr g 0 xs
  where
  g x rec = if elem x "aeiou" then 1 + rec else rec
```